# Postfix Server for Mass Mailing on Multiple Domains

Tags: email, postfix, bulk

I'm currently setting up a mail server for mass mailing on a non-profit. I decided to go with Postfix since I had some experience with the configuration. However my experience was for multi domain environments backed by a MySQL DB not a mass mailing solution.

What I'm trying to accomplish needs to meet the following:

1. SMTP server that allows to send emails from any email address / domain they choose;
2. Only allow to send the emails with those domains from the server itself, to avoid running this as an open-relay and have spam issues;
3. Still have a `virtual_aliases`, `mailbox-domains`, `mailbox-maps` configuration based on a MySQL DB so I can create internal emails `@massmail.example` to use as email bounce / return path to track errors;

My current config is a multi domain environment, I'm able to add domains and users into the MySQL DB like `bounces@massmail.example`, connect to SMTP, send mail and receive over IMAP. Everything works fine.

However, how am I supposed to implement the part: "send emails from any email address / domain they choose"?

To send emails from `news@non-profit.com`, should I:

1. Add the domain `non-profit.com` to the `virtual_domains` table and create the user `news@non-profit.com` at the `virtual_users`, login with that address and send the emails?
2. Login with the internal bounce email `bounces@massmail.example` use it to send email but change the `FROM` header to `news@non-profit.com`?

What's the correct options in terms of SPAM detection bulk sending compliance? Any of the above or something else? How does platforms like mail chimp handle this?

I tried the option (2) and gmail, for instance, says something like this:
[image]

Comment: For mass mailing you should probably use a mail list application (or a 3rd party service), and not implement your own.

Comment: @Rabin not possible due to budget.

Comment: some services (like mailchimp) will give a free usage if the list is < 2000 or 12000 mails per month.

Comment: @Rabin I had this discussion with them already, not worth it. I really want to do this for them and for me, it still has a big learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have mass mailing, without SPAMMING, unless users have registered, and approved their email address, or any other 2 factor acknowledgment.

Restrict MTA to IP, edit main.cf and add the IP's you wish to send from.
i.e... inet_interfaces = public-ip,127.0.0.1

create a generic map for the different domains they wish to send from.
see for example: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-postfix-masquerade-change-email-mail-address.html

Comment: Yes, I'll ask permission to send email. Users will sign physical a form with other stuff and they have an option to opt out... The same option will be send at the bottom of every email. Thanks for the reply I'll take a look at the link.